# How many pointers are in an array of pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I dynamically allocated memory for 3D array of pointers. My question is how many pointers do I have? I mean, do I have X·Y number of pointers pointing to an array of double or X·Y·Z pointers pointing to a double element or is there another variant?

```
double*** arr;
arr = (double***)calloc(X, sizeof(double));
for (int i = 0; i < X; ++i) {
    *(arr + i) = (double**)calloc(Y, sizeof(double));
        for (int k = 0; k < Y; ++k) {
            *(*(arr+i) + k) = (double*)calloc(Z, sizeof(double));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Rather than messing with pointers, you could create a one dimensional array that is the size of the 3d array, then use 3d indexing to access the slots.

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag because your code is clearly C. Would you like a C++ answer? It will likely involve using `std::vector<double>` instead of `double***`

Comment: `arr = (double***)calloc(X, sizeof(double));` ,,-- Wong. Hint: dont try to be a three-star programmer.

Comment: Do you really need a 3d array of double pointers? A 3d array of doubles  maybe is enough? You don't mention the problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you apparently intended to write would start:

```
double ***arr = calloc(X, sizeof *arr);
```

Notes:

- Here we define one pointer, `arr`, and set it to point to memory provided by `calloc`.
- Using `sizeof (double)` with this is wrong; `arr` is going to point to things of type `double **`, so we want the size of that. The `sizeof` operator accepts either types in parentheses or objects. So we can write `sizeof *arr` to mean “the size of a thing that `arr` will point to”. This always gets the right size for whatever `arr` points to; we never have to figure out the type.
- There is no need to use `calloc` if we are going to assign values to all of the elements. We can use just `double ***arr = malloc(X * sizeof *arr);`.
- In C, there is no need to cast the return value of `calloc` or `malloc`. Its type is `void *`, and the compiler will automatically convert that to whatever pointer type we assign it to. If the compiler complains, you are probably using a C++ compiler, not a C compiler, and the rules are different.
- You should check the return value from `calloc` or `malloc` in case not enough memory was available. For brevity, I omit showing the code for that.

Then the code would continue:

```
for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < X; ++i)
{
    arr[i] = calloc(Y, sizeof *arr[i]);
    …
}
```

Notes:

- Here we assign values to the *X* pointers that `arr` points to.
- `ptrdiff_t` is defined in `stddef.h`. You should generally use it for array indices, unless there is a reason to use another type.
- `arr[i]` is equivalent to `*(arr + i)` but is generally easier for humans to read and think about.
- As before `sizeof *arr[i]` automatically gives us the right size for the pointer we are setting, `arr[i]`.
  Finally, the `…` in there is:

```
        for (ptrdiff_t k = 0; k < Y; ++k)
            arr[i][k] = calloc(Z, sizeof *arr[i][k]);
```

Notes:

- Here we assign values to the *Y* pointers that `arr[i]` points to, and this loop is inside the loop on `i` that executes *X* times, so this code assigns *XY* pointers in total.

So the answer to your question is we have 1 + *X* + *XY* pointers.

Nobody producing good commercial code uses this. Using pointers-to-pointers-to-pointers is bad for the hardware (meaning inefficient in performance) because the processor generally cannot predict where a pointer points to until it fetches it. Accessing some member of your array, `arr[i][j][k]`, requires loading three pointers from memory.

In most C implementations, you can simply allocate a three-dimensional array:

```
double (*arr)[Y][Z] = calloc(X, sizeof *arr);
```

With this, when you access `arr[i][j][k]`, the compiler will calculate the address (as, in effect, `arr + (i*Y + j)*Z + k`). Although that involves several multiplications and additions, they are fairly simple for modern processors and are likely as fast or faster than fetching pointers from memory and they leave the processor’s load-store unit free to fetch the actual array data. Also, when you are using the same `i` and/or `j` repeatedly, the compiler likely generates code that keeps `i*Y` and/or `(i*Y + j)*Z` around for multiple uses without recalculating them.

Answer (score -1):

Well, short answer is: **it is not known**.

As a classic example, keep in mind the `main()` prototype

```
    int    main( int argc, char** argv);
```

`argc` keeps the number of pointers. Without it we do not know how many they are. The system builds the array `argv`, gently updates `argc` with the value and then launches the program.

#### Back to your array

```
    double*** arr;
```

All you know is that

- `arr` is a pointer.
- `*arr` is `double**`, also a pointer
- `**arr` is `double*`, also a pointer
- `***arr` is a `double`.

What you will get in code depends on how you build this. A common way if you need an array of arrays and things like that is to mimic the system and use a few `unsigned` and wrap them all with the pointers into a `struct` like

```
typedef struct
{
    int         n_planes;
    int         n_rows;
    int         n_columns;
    double***   array;

}   Cube;
```

A CSV file for example is `char ** **`, a sheet workbook is `char ** ** **` and it is a bit scary, but works. For each `**` a counter is needed, as said above about `main()`

#### A C example

The code below uses `arr`, declared as `double***`, to

- store a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a `double`

  - prints the value using the 3 pointers
- then uses `arr` again to build a *cube* of `X*Y*Z` doubles, using a bit of math to set values to 9XY9.Z9

  - the program uses 2, 3 and 4 for a total of 24 values
  - lists the full array
  - list the first and the very last element, `arr[0][0][0]` and `arr[X-1][Y-1][Z-1]`
  - frees the whole thing in reverse order

### The code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int         n_planes;
    int         n_rows;
    int         n_columns;
    double***   array;

}   Cube;

int         print_array(double***, int, int, int);

int main(void)
{

    double   sample = 20.21;
    double*  pDouble = &sample;
    double** ppDouble = &pDouble;

    double*** arr = &ppDouble;

    printf("***arr is %.2ff\n", ***arr);
    printf("original double is %.2ff\n", sample);
    printf("*pDouble is %.2ff\n", *pDouble);
    printf("**ppDouble is %.2ff\n", **ppDouble);

    // but we can build a cube of XxYxZ doubles for arr
    int  X = 2;
    int  Y = 3;
    int  Z = 4; // 24 elements

    arr = (double***)malloc(X * sizeof(double**));
    // now each arr[i] must point to an array of double**
    for (int i = 0; i < X; i += 1)
    {
        arr[i] = (double**)malloc(Y * sizeof(double*));
        for (int j = 0; j < Y; j += 1)
        {
            arr[i][j] = (double*)malloc(Z * sizeof(double));
            for (int k = 0; k < Z; k += 1)
            {
                arr[i][j][k] = (100. * i) + (10. * j) + (.1 * k) + 9009.09;
            }
        }
    }
    print_array(arr, X, Y, Z);
    printf("\n\
Test: first element is arr[%d][%d[%d] = %6.2f (9XY9.Z9)\n\
       last element is arr[%d][%d[%d] = %6.2f (9XY9.Z9)\n",
        0, 0, 0, arr[0][0][0],
        (X-1), (Y-1), (Z-1), arr[X-1][Y-1][Z-1]
    );

    // now to free this monster
    for (int x = 0; x < X; x += 1)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < Y; y += 1)
        {
            free(arr[x][y]); // the Z rows
        }
        free(arr[x]); // the plane Y
    }
    free(arr); // the initial pointer;
    return 0;
};  // main()

int         print_array(double*** block, int I, int J, int K)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < I; a += 1)
    {
        printf("\nPlane %d\n\n", a);
        for (int b = 0; b < J; b += 1)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < K; c += 1)
            {
                printf("%6.2f ", block[a][b][c]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
};  // print_array()
```

### The output

```
***arr is 20.21f
original double is 20.21f
*pDouble is 20.21f
**ppDouble is 20.21f

Plane 0

9009.09 9009.19 9009.29 9009.39
9019.09 9019.19 9019.29 9019.39
9029.09 9029.19 9029.29 9029.39

Plane 1

9109.09 9109.19 9109.29 9109.39
9119.09 9119.19 9119.29 9119.39
9129.09 9129.19 9129.29 9129.39 

Test: first element is arr[0][0[0] = 9009.09 (9XY9.Z9)
       last element is arr[1][2[3] = 9129.39 (9XY9.Z9)
```

Comment: funny to see this answer flagged as not useful. Is it off-topic? unrelated?

Comment: please do not bother pointing out that in C is not needed to cast the `void*` pointer returned by `malloc()`. This idea comes from the '90s [C-faq](http://c-faq.com). Using casts makes things clearer in code that allocates many things in sequence as, well, the  code above.  See C++ for this. For the compiler it makes no difference. But for the programmer can be helpful.